# Odoo v8 form with WTForms

Tags: python, forms, odoo, wtforms, openerp-8

I'm trying to accomplish this but I'm not sure how.

Let's say I have form with two mandatory fields `name` and `partner_id`

On this form I have some other fields, which I want to fill from a website form, like this for example:

```
class CuidumForm(Form):
    name = StringField(_('Nombre periodical'),
        [Required(_('Please enter a name for the invoicing'))])
    nombre = StringField(_('Nombre'),
        [Required(_('Please enter a name for the Partner'))])
    n_seguridad_social = StringField(_('N de Seguridad Social'))#, [
    fecha_nacimiento = DateField(_('Fecha de nacimiento'),
        format='%d/%m/%Y', validators=(validators.Optional(),) )
    grado_discapacidad = StringField(_('Grado de discapacidad'))
    partner_id = SelectField(_('Country'), coerce=int)
```

My problem is, as I said before, that this module form, has `name` and `partner_id` as mandatory. So, everytime I create a new form like this, I'm creating a whole new register, while I just want to fill the other fields.

What I'm confused at, is the fact that I should relate this website form to the form which is loading it, or, put it into another form, take `name` and `partner_id` as parameters of this form, and fill the other fields from `@route` in website.

I don't know if I'm explaining very well, I need some example like this to complete my task.

Somebody has an idea to where I should look for, or maybe a solution?

I'm quite confused on how to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I have this controller, which loads the form on browser:

```
class Cuidum(Controller):

@route('/contrato/crear', type='http', auth='public',website=True)
def create(self, **post_data):
    form = CuidumForm(request.httprequest.form)
    form.partner_id.choices = [
        (partner.id, partner.name)
        for partner in request.env['res.partner'].search([])
    ]
    if request.httprequest.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        request.env['account.periodical_invoicing.agreement'].create(dict([
            (field_name, field.data)
            for field_name, field in form._fields.iteritems()
        ]))
        return request.render(
            'website_create_partner.success',
            {'name': form.name.data})
    return request.render(
        'website_create_partner.contrato_new',
        {'form': form})
```

The key is here I guess:

```
form.partner_id.choices = [
    (partner.id, partner.name)
    for partner in request.env['res.partner'].search([])
]
```

How can I change this, from searching for a partner, to taking the actual `partner_id` which created the form?

**SECOND EDIT**

I'll try to explain myself better

Let's say I have a form view in backend, this form view has the fields: `'name','partner_id','field_1','field_2','field_3'`, as I said `name` and `partner_id` are mandatory, so, all these fields, mandatory or not, can be filled from this form view, when you create or edit one, ok...

Now, with this website form I'm creating, I just want to EDIT the backend form view, let's say from the form view, I have a button, this button loads the WTForm in website, with fields: `field_1,field_2,field_3` and taking as parameters the fields `name` and `partner_id`, and my problem now, is that the website form is just creating a new form view, not editing or updating the document.

I should launch this WTForm froma button and I don't know, I should take a dict or a context with `name` and `partner_id` from where I'm launching it.

I hope this explains my issue better.

Comment: Good thought , Use Flask Forms in odoo +1

I just don't understand what is actual problem (last two line)

Comment: Hi, Thx, the problem is that this form is creating a new 'account,periodical.invoicing' object, and in reality, I just want to open this form having the  'name' and 'partner_id' of the form I'm editing, you see? Not really creating a new one

Comment: I mean, imagine you are on a form, in backend, with a button, you load this other form in website, however, my point is, that the backend form, has 'name' and 'partner_id' fields as mandatory, but I don't want to add a new backend form, I just want to open the website one, having the 'name' and the 'partner_id' from where I'm launching the website form.

Comment: The 'name' and 'partner_id' of the backend form , from where I'm launching the website one.

Comment: I've edited my question, I hope that explains it a little better